# PostgreSQL Replace Column Data with Unique Integers

Tags: database, postgresql, replace

I have a table of many columns in `Postgresql` database. Some of these columns are in text type and have several rows of values. The values also recur. I would like to change these text values with unique integer values.

This is my table column:

```
Country_Name
------------
USA
Japan
Mexico
USA
USA
Japan
England
```

and the new column I want is:

```
Country_Name
------------
1
2
3
1
1
2
4
```

Each country name is assigned (mapped) to a unique integer and all the recurrences of the text is replaced with this number. How can I do this?

Edit 1: I want to replace my column values on the fly if possible. I don't actually need another column to keep the names but it would be nice to see the actual values too. Is it possible to do:

- Create a column `country_id` with the same values of `country_name` column in the same table
- And for `country_id` replace each name with a unique integer with an update statement or procedure without requiring a new table or dictionary or map.

I don't know if this is possible but this will speed up things because I have a total of 220 columns and millions of rows. Thank you.

Comment: Create a mapping table using `SELECT DISTINCT`. Then update while joining to the mapping table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*assuming the `country_name` column is in a table called `country_data`*

create a new table & populate with unique country_names

```
-- valid in pg10 onwards
-- for earlier versions use SERIAL instead in the PK definition
CREATE TABLE countries (
   country_id INT  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   country_name TEXT); 
INSERT INTO countries (country_name) 
SELECT DISTINCT country_name
FROM country_data;
```

alter the table `country_data` & add a column `country_id`

```
ALTER TABLE country_data ADD COLUMN country_id INT
```

Join `country_data` to `countries` and populate the `country_id` column

```
UPDATE country_data
SET country_id = s.country_id
FROM countries
WHERE country_data.country_name = countries.country_name
```

At this point the `country_id` is available to query, but a few following actions may be recommended depending on the use case:

- set up `country_data.country_id` as a foreign key referring to `countries.country_id`
- drop the column `country_data.country_name` as that's redundant through the relationship with `countries`
- *maybe* create an index on `country_data.country_id` if you determine that it will speed up the queries you normally run on this table.

Comment: i'd advise against generating this on the fly for performance & storage reasons. also depending on the data access method, two on-the-fly queries might map countries to different ids.